# What method will get called when multiple classes implement 1 service contract interface

Tags: .net, wcf, interface

This could be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717678/multiple-wcf-services-implementing-same-service-contract-interface) but the answer received there did not answer my query and also I was not able to find it on the net.

Taking the example given in the question mentioned above, when I create an endpoint on the client side I write an endpoint with the contract as an interface. So my endpoint on the client side will be something similar to the following.

```
<client>
    <endpoint name="MyClientEndpoint" address="http://..." binding="basicHttpBinding"
     contract="IUselessService" />
</client>
```

Also in code on client side I create an object of the proxy and call the method i.e. `GetData`.

So my question here is method of which class will get called? `TestService` or `RealService`? Because nowhere on the client side i am mentioning method of which class should get called.

I am sure there will be some setting somewhere in WCF to make sure the method of the correct class gets called but I am not able to find it.

Also I am a little new to WCF so please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Samar

Comment: It depends on which implementation the `ServiceHost` is using -if it's using `TestService` then that implementation's method will be called.  If it's using `RealService` then the implementation in `RealService` will be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, a `ServiceHost` will host a specific implementation of a contract.  It's the `ServiceHost` that determines the implementation of the service contract - the client has no knowledge of the actual implementation, just the methods available from the service it is connecting to via the proxy.

So, for example, if the client is connecting to `http://somedomain.com/MyService.svc`, and the service host that is exposing that endpoint is using `RealService`, then the implementation of the `IUselessService` is what the client will ultimately be using.

In a self-hosted service, the service might look something like this:

```
ServiceHost myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RealService), new Uri("http://somedomain.com/MyService"));
```

Any client connecting to `http://somedomain.com/MyService` would use `RealService`'s implementation of the contract.

On the other hand, say you're hosting `TestService` in IIS, at `http://somedomain.com/MyService.svc`.  In that case, you'll have a .svc file that will look something like this (and similar to what Grzegorz posted):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="True" Service="TestService" %>
```

(I usually fully qualify the service name when I host in IIS).

The corresponding web.config file might contain the following endpoint:

```
<service name="TestService">
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IUselessService" />
</service>
```

In this case, it will be `TestService`'s implementation of the contract that will be accessed.

So, in a nutshell, at least as I understand it, the service host determines the implementation of the contract (through the class it is hosting), and a given service host can only have one implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If You are hosting on IIS You are probably using endpoint address pointing to file like 'Useless.svc'.
Inside this file You configure the implementation:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TestService" CodeBehind="TestService.cs" %>
```

Or you could create a custom [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx) to provide different implementations based on url or configuration.